# Using composer on small projects

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I want to use composer on my small Php-project (pure PHP, no frameworks), and i want to get some libraries (jquery, bootstrap) by composer, when i get jquery, composer pulling some symfony and kriswallsmith dependencies, they are nessaserry and I just need to ignore them?

Links :

https://packagist.org/packages/twbs/bootstrap

https://packagist.org/packages/components/jquery

Composer:

```
{
    "require" : {
        "components/jquery": "dev-master",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "3.2.*@dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the packages on [packagist](https://packagist.org/) that you have used?

Comment: i added link to question body)

Comment: Can you show us your `composer.json`, because these packages don't seem to have any dependencies.

Comment: Stop using Composer for UI dependencies. Use Bower or some other similar tool for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer is a PHP dependency manager. It is created for one specific goal: Management of PHP packages.

You should not use Composer to include any package from another language, it isn't created for it and it is really not good in it. For Javascript/HTML/CSS packages, you should take a look at [Bower](http://bower.io).

> Btw, none of the packages you named in your post are installed because of the packages you listed in your code. Use `composer depends ...` (where `...` is the package name) to see why there were included.